# Does including images in a sitemap.xml as unique pages have any negative affect on SEO?

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index

So I know that the correct way of identifying pages in a sitemap is like this:

```html
<url>
   <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
</url>
```

If I want to include images in the sitemap, I know that I need to include the image extension and I could then include images like this:

```html
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
  <image:image>
    <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
  </image:image>
</url>
```

My question is, what if I'm using a software that generates the sitemap without an image extension and instead adds images like this:

```html
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/image.jpg</loc>
</url>
```

I know that Google is ignoring those images (at least it is ignoring them in webmaster) but could this have any negative affect on the functionality of the sitemap.xml file? I know that Google will ignore all canonical tags of a website if there are too many that point to deceptive or error pages — does this same concept apply to sitemaps that have URLs that are not pointing to indexable webpages? Is any documentation on something like this?

Comment: Why you're doing that? Any good reason.

Comment: I'm not doing it which is the point of the question.

Comment: I have never done that, but I think it will treat, same as other webpages with .php and .aspx extension. I don't think there is any negative effect, because if there is any penalty then it will low quality or thin content, and Google don't consider photos as low quality. There are some gallery website, who open image, completely in new url, and google don't treat them as low quality webpage.

Answer (score -2):

As per my experience it will not have any negative effect upon SEO.  However, you must create a separate sitemap for your image collection which will works better in terms of search engine algorithms. That way, Googlebot will find the already segregated data (Page, Image, Post etc) for their crawling perspective.

For example you should go through Yoast plugin sitemap structure.

PFA screen-shot here. About what i am talking? **[Image sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en)**

[image]

Comment: Can you expand upon your experience with image URLs directly in `<loc>` in a sitemap?    I've never heard of anybody doing that before.   Why would you have done it?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I know you have a vast experience in that field but you never heard about it from anybody because Nobody actually cares about the Google Guidelines. Plz refer the attachment in the above edited Answer by Me.

Comment: Thank you for editing in more information.  That screenshot puts the images in `<image:loc>` tags, not directly into the `<loc>` tags as the person who asked the question.